# How to set wetness and dryness of a convolver filter in the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, convolution

Is there another way of doing this? I found this code example in where the mixing is controlled with two gain nodes. Is this how it is normally done?

```
// impulse responses by Fokke van Saane (http://fokkie.home.xs4all.nl/IR.htm)
// author: andre.michelle@gmail.com

var context = new AudioContext();
var audioElement = document.getElementById('player');
var carrier = context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
var convolver = context.createConvolver();
var dry = context.createGain();
var wet = context.createGain();

carrier.connect( convolver );

convolver.connect(wet);
carrier.connect(dry);

dry.connect( context.destination );
wet.connect( context.destination );

var mix = function( value ) {
    dry.gain.value = ( 1.0 - value );
    wet.gain.value = value;
}

var loadImpulse = function ( fileName )
{
  var url = "http://files.andre-michelle.com/impulse/" + fileName;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open( "GET", url, true );
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  request.onload = function ()
  {
    context.decodeAudioData( request.response, function ( buffer ) {
      convolver.buffer = buffer;
    }, function ( e ) { console.log( e ); } );
  };request.onerror = function ( e )
  {
    console.log( e );
  };
  request.send();
};

loadImpulse(document.getElementById('impulse').value);
mix(1.0);

function changeValue(string,type)
{
  var value = parseFloat(string) / 100.0;

  switch(type)
  {
    case 'mix':
        mix(value);
      break;
  }
}
```

[Code Source](https://codepen.io/jHollond/pen/yXbZGj)

I've tried this code example, but, since I'm dealing with a ton of audio clips, I want to know if there is a correct or more performant way of mixing the convolver node wetness and dryness.